# Function template explicit specialization c++

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, explicit

My book mentions two ways for explicit specialization:

```
template <> void Swap<int> (int &, int &);
template <> void Swap(int &, int&);
```

what is the difference between both? when to use one and when to use the other? what is exactly the <> after the function name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the difference between both?

**There is no difference**.

In the second case, you are letting the compiler perform *type deduction* from the signature of the specialization. Therefore, both forms declare a specialization of `Swap<T>()` for `T = int`.

> when to use one and when to use the other?

At your discretion, when one form or the other meets your requirements in terms of readability or ease of maintenance.

> what is exactly the <> after the function name?

When it comes *after the function name*, it is the syntax for specifying template arguments:

```
template<typename T = double, typename U = char>
void foo();

foo<int, bool>(); // Specifies explicit template arguments
foo<>(); // Use default template arguments
foo(); // Same as above, allowed for *function* templates only
```

When it comes *after the* `template` *keyword*, it is the syntax for introducing a (class or function) template specialization.

Comment: What if... `template <> void Swap( int a, char b)`?

Comment: @xgbi: Type deduction fails

Comment: @xgbi I supposed the function defines something like Swap(T&, T&) so you may not be able to write that.

Comment: Say we have a template that takes two variables Type1 t and Type2 u as parameters. Is it possible to define an explicit specialization when only one of the parameters is specific? Ex: when t is an int, u can be anything. Is it possible?

Comment: @jazzybazz: No, function templates cannot be partially specialized. But you can create two *overloads* (one with two template arguments, one with one template argument).

Comment: What if the template contains two different types, say Type1 T and Type2 U....and I want to specialize when T is an int and U is a double...what would I write in the <> ?

Comment: @jazzybazz: Judging from your profile, it seems you do not accept any of the answers people give to your questions, and you keep asking new questions in the comments. This is not a good way of using StackOverflow.

Comment: @jazzybazz: Anyway, that would be `template<> void Swap<int, double>(int &, double &)`, or just let it deduce: `template<> void Swap(int &, double &)`

Answer (score 1):

The first example is the real way to explicitly specialize a template, the second example is just a shortcut for the first way since the compiler can deduced the type itself from the function signature. **The result is the same**, there is no real difference.

The `<>`is used to give the template parameter to a templated structure, in this case the template parameter is the type of the manipulated data and the specialization is for the type `int`.